# Linq GroupBy With Passed Where Predicate

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This works fine.`g.Key` is not null and has appropriate data:

```
var result = db.JournalEntries.Include(je => je.JournalRecords.Select(jr => jr.Account).Select(j => j.AccountParticulars))
                .Where(je => je.Date >= existingLedgerTransaction.From && je.Date <= existingLedgerTransaction.To)
                .SelectMany(s => s.JournalRecords)
                .GroupBy(d => d.AccountParticular.Account.AccountCategory)
                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key.Name });
```

But this does not work as `g.Key` is null:

```
var DateFilter = new Func<JournalEntry, bool>(je => je.Date >= existingLedgerTransaction.From && je.Date <= existingLedgerTransaction.To);

var result = db.JournalEntries.Include(je => je.JournalRecords.Select(jr => jr.Account).Select(j => j.AccountParticulars))
                .Where(DateFilter)
                .SelectMany(s => s.JournalRecords)
                .GroupBy(d => d.AccountParticular.Account.AccountCategory)
                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key.Name });
```

I tried the same thing in a simple console app with static collection and passing in predicate works fine. What could be the problem here?

NOTE: Lazy loading/dynamic proxy is disabled

Comment: Why  not just add `Where(g => g.Key != null)` before the last `Select` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 var DateFilter = new Expression<Func<JournalEntry, bool>>(je => je.Date >= existingLedgerTransaction.From && je.Date <= existingLedgerTransaction.To);
```

as you need to pass an expression tree to EF

Comment: Yes, `Expression` works. But I had to write it like this: `Expression<Func<JournalEntry, bool>> DateFilter = je => je.Date >= existingLedgerTransaction.From && je.Date <= existingLedgerTransaction.To`. Otherwise it throws me error saying `Expression<TDelegate>` does not take 1 arguments. I wonder why.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, you have to let the C# compiler to create a new expression from a Lambda, than it is from creating your own via the constructor etc. 
The constructor for a new expression is: `protected Expression(
 ExpressionType nodeType,
 Type type
)`

Comment: you wouldn't be creating an `Expression` type, but instead one of its derived types. E.g. `ConditionalExpression` which the compiler creates for you when you use a lambda.